# Hosting Octopress on FreeBSD

Tags: ruby, apache, freebsd, octopress

Recently tried to setup hosting a test Octopress website for my own blogging-purposes. 
Can't really get this working on FreeBSD (with Apache) so any help is much appreciated.

Installed all the needed stuff (and extra):

```
/usr/ports # cd devel/subversion
/usr/ports/editors/vim-lite/
/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster
```

Entered RUBY_DEFAULT_VER=1.9 in make.conf

```
portmaster converters/ruby-iconv 
portmaster /usr/ports/sysutils/rubygem-bundler
```

All dependencies will be installed - including Ruby

```
git clone git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git /usr/local/www/apache2/data/octopress
cd /usr/local/www/apache2/data/octopress
ruby --version
```

Everything SHOULD be ok, now defined the vhost in Apache.

```
gem install bundler
rehash
bundle install
rake install
```

Also ok

I see the public directory now but nothing like Ruby / Octopress. I suppose I missed some necessary steps. Do I need to install something else to link my Ruby environment with Apache?

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer for this question if you post it on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Comment: No problem. You could also try posting on the [FreeBSD Forums](http://forums.freebsd.org/) -- the people there are knowledgeable and usually very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to run `rake generate` to actually generate output in the `public` directory.